# Releasing an int?

Tags: ios, int

That may be a stupid question, but if I declare a int variable in my .h file, do I need to release it  in (void)dealloc of the .m ?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only objects can be released, not the C primitive types, such as int.